# How do I get the delete key to work properly

Tags: shell

I'm on a linux box:

```
jla@jaspden-desktop$ uname -a

Linux jaspden-desktop 2.6.35.13-92.fc14.i686 #1 SMP Sat May 21 17:39:42 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

here, at the command prompt, the backspace key deletes the character behind the cursor, and the delete key deletes the character underneath the cursor.

I log in remotely to another box of ours:

```
$ ssh anvil
Last login: Thu Sep 15 11:58:38 2011 from maspben-desktop.uk.level5networks.com

$ uname -a
Linux anvil 2.6.9-89.ELlargesmp #1 SMP Mon Apr 20 10:43:12 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Now the backspace key still works as before, but the delete key doesn't delete anything. Instead, it inserts a tilde like so:

```
jla@anvil$ misspell~ling
```

If I then run tcsh on the remote box,

```
$ tcsh
```

The delete key works as if it were backspace, deleting the character behind the cursor.

If I go back to bash, it reverts to its tilde-inserting mode.

Any ideas how to fix/debug this? It's driving me up the wall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two guides to help you understand and hopefully fix the backspace and delete keys in various shells and other command line applications:

- [Linux Backspace/Delete mini-HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/BackspaceDelete/)
- [Consistent BackSpace and Delete Configuration](http://www.ibb.net/~anne/keyboard.html)

They have helped me solve this kind of problems many times.

I have refrained from quoting the "most relevant" part, because any part of those documents could be the most relevant for you, it depends on the specifics of your systems.

Comment: Thanks! That was enough information to sort it out. I needed to modify .inputrc for bash and .cshrc for tcsh.